# react -redux component does not re-render after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have been trying and trying by my component wont re-render itself . Below is my reducer code and I have tried everything to not mutate the state. In my component code ,inside render method, I have a log statement   console.log("Check Here"); I know the component does not re-render because this log works first time the component renders but after reducer changes the state the log statement is not called . In logs I can clearly see that  prev state and next state are different by just that one SearchType that I am changing. Please help!!

```
const initState = {

    searchType: ""

};
const techniqueReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
   switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypeConstants.GET_SEARCH:
  {
     return { ...state, searchType: "new string" };    
  }

  default: {
    return state;
  }

}
};

export default myReducer;
```

My component code is below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as tDispatchers from "../actions/Actions";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
  
    searchType: state.searchType
  };
};

class SearchCollection extends Component {

  Search= () => {
    this.props.dispatch(tDispatchers.getSearch(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value));
  }
 
  render() {
    console.log("Check Here")

    return (
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div>

          <input
            type="text"
            id="txtSearch"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Search Keywords Here..."
          />
        </div>
        <div>
    <button
            className="btn btn-light btn-sm m-1"
            onClick={this.Search}
          >
            Search
          </button>
         

        </div>
  
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchCollection);
```

GetSearch looks like below
I plan to pass payload to reducer eventually but currently I am not

```
import * as actionTypeConstants from "../action_type_constants";
import axios from "axios";

export function getSearch(searchtext) {

    return dispatchFunction => {
      axios
      .get("<api call>"+searchtext)
      .then(response => {

          dispatchFunction({
            type: actionTypeConstants.GET_SEARCH,
            payload: response.data.data
          });
        })
      };

    }
```

ActionTypeConstant

```
export const GET_SEARCH = "GET_SEARCH";
```

Comment: return { ...state, SearchType: "new string" }; bad spelling ? searchType ?

Comment: Can you post the component code in question? Please include the mapping of state and dispatch code.

Comment: I have edited the question.. the capitalization error happened when I was modifying the code little bit to post here

Comment: i have added component code

Comment: @kimi86 Can you also include `getSearchTechniques` and `actionTypeConstants.GET_SEARCH` in the snippet? :)

Comment: done @karlmarxlopez

Comment: @kimi86, check my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206377/discussion-between-karlmarxlopez-and-kimi86).

Comment: @karlmarxlopez - I did that but it did not work. So i am just hardcoding a string value for now eventually i plan to pass payload to reducer

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating `searchType` value, which is hardcoded to string `new string`. Try setting the new state from the action, for example:

```js
return { ...state, searchType: action.payload};
```

Or check this, https://jsfiddle.net/xt3sqoc6/1/ and open your dev tools to see the rerenders.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using redux-thunk to work with async actions. But you don't return an async function from `getSearch`. I believe it should be

```
export function getSearch(searchtext) {
  return dispatchFunction => {
    return axios
      .get("<api call>"+searchtext)
      .then(response => {
        dispatchFunction({
          type: actionTypeConstants.GET_SEARCH,
          payload: response.data.data
        });
      })
  };
}
```

or

```
export function getSearch(searchtext) {
  return async dispatchFunction => {
    const response = await axios
      .get("<api call>"+searchtext);
    dispatchFunction({
      type: actionTypeConstants.GET_SEARCH,
      payload: response.data.data
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)`. It is invoked immediately after updating occurs & you can compare the current props to previous props. Using that you can re-render your component by changing `state`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.SearchType !== prevProps.SearchType) {
    //Do whatever needs to happen!
  }
}
```

You may call `setState()` immediately in `componentDidUpdate` but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: This is only useful for the local component state. OP is clearly using redux, based on the snippet.

Comment: @karlmarxlopez is right, this has likely nothing to do with the issue at hand. You should probably not be so defensive in your comments. :)

Comment: @segFault he said this lifecycle only useful with local state. but that is wrong.  this issue may be occurred to a different error. but using this you can check your prop changes.

Comment: @SDushan I know what `componentDidUpdate` do, and I always read the docs :). But, you clearly said, "You may call setState immediately" which has nothing to do with `redux`. Even if you replace `setState` with a `dispatch` call, I think that is still a bad practice to do.

Comment: I added componentDidUpdate in my component and even that did not trigger   componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.searchType !== prevProps.searchType) {
      console.log("True");
    }
    else {
        console.log("False");
    }
  }